# Integração com o SIGEP dos Correios

Tags: php, api, web-service

Estou precisando fazer uma integração com o API SIGEP dos Correios apenas para gerar as etiquetas. Estou usando o módulo já pronto do GitHub (https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep).

Ele faz a conexão normalmente, mas o retorno que os Correios dá é "Não foi possível obter as etiquetas solicitadas."

Perguntei ao pessoal dos Correios e eles informaram que é porque não é possível mais fazer a solicitação apenas das etiquetas, sendo necessárias as seguintes integrações antes:

- Verificar status do cartão
- Solicitar dados do contrato/cartão
- E só então solicitar as etiquetas

O engraçado é que o modelo que o módulo do GitHub tem não faz nada disso, e no site modelo faz parecer que eles conectam direto.

Alguém poderia me ajudar em como posso fazer?

Comment: o git em questão tem um exemplo funcional (que está funcionando). tentou baixar e rodar no seu ambiente?

Comment: Sim, testei os 3 exemplos que vem no pacote, e os 3 retornam o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agradeço a ajuda, mas cheguei a uma solução própria.

Caso se interessem, segue a classe abaixo.

A classe conecta mencionada (e relacionada à classe por composição no método construtor) é de autoria minha e é apenas para conexão ao banco de dados. (Detalhes sobre ela podem ser vistos aqui: https://www.facebook.com/notes/tmw-technology/classe-conecta-7-auxiliando-voc%C3%AA-na-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-seu-banco-de-dados-phpmysql/516582278382242)

No método **getData()** são verificados os dados do banco de dados e se a loja em questão comprou o pacote de integração com o SIGEP (**$this->lojaAutorizada**).

Apenas essa parte é que vocês terão que adaptar caso desejem fazer uso dessa classe.

```
<?php
/**
* SIGEP WEB - Geração de etiquetas
* @author TMW E-commerce Solutions
*/

require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'conecta.class.php';

class Sigep
{
    const
        SIGEP = 'https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl'; # API Url

    private
        $soap,                  # conexão soap
        $result,                # resultado das pesquisas
        $pdo,                   # conexão com PDO
        $dadosCliente,          # dados do cliente junto ao SIGEP
        $servicos = array(),    # servicos disponiveis
        $cnpj = NULL;           # CNPJ do cliente

    public
        $erro = '',                 # erros no processamento
        $sql = '',                  # execuções de sql
        $lojaAutorizada = false,    # autoriza o processamento?
        $servicoConectado = false;  # possui todos os dados?

    /**
    * Método Construtor
    */
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->pdo = new Conecta('sigep');

        $this->getData();
    }

    /**
    * Verifica dados
    * @access private
    */
    private function getData( $registerSql = true )
    {
        // Busca os dados do cliente se estiverem ativos
        $this->pdo->zeraVars();
        $this->pdo->setVars(array(
            'where' => 'sig_ativo = 1',
            'oneRow' => true
        ));
        $this->dadosCliente = $this->pdo->execute();
        if ( $registerSql ) $this->sql = $this->pdo->sql;

        // Cliente está ativo?
        if( ! isset( $this->dadosCliente->sig_ativo ) || $this->dadosCliente->sig_ativo != 1 ):

            $this->lojaAutorizada = false;
            $this->erro = 'Loja não autorizada';    

        else:

            // Se está ativo, inicializa o serviço
            $this->lojaAutorizada = true;
            $this->startService();

        endif;        
    }

    /**
    * Inicializa o serviço
    * @access public
    */
    private function startService()
    {
        // Loja autorizada?
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada ):

            try{
                $this->soap = new SoapClient('https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl');

                // Verifica Cartão de Postagem
                $soapArgs = array(
                    'numeroCartaoPostagem'  => $this->dadosCliente->sig_cartao,
                    'usuario'               => $this->dadosCliente->sig_user,
                    'senha'                 => $this->dadosCliente->sig_pass
                );

                // Resultados possíveis de $result->return: Normal | Cancelado
                $this->result = $this->soap->getStatusCartaoPostagem( $soapArgs );        

            } catch( Exception $e ) {

                $this->erro = 'Erro ao verificar cartão de postagem: ' . $e->getMessage();
                $this->servicoConectado = false;

            }

            try{

                if( $this->result->return == 'Normal' ):

                    // Busca os dados do Cliente, incluindo o código dos serviços de postagem
                    $soapArgs = array(
                        'idContrato'       => $this->dadosCliente->sig_contrato,
                        'idCartaoPostagem' => $this->dadosCliente->sig_cartao,
                        'usuario'          => $this->dadosCliente->sig_user,
                        'senha'            => $this->dadosCliente->sig_pass
                    );

                    // Retorna os serviços disponíveis para o cliente, bem como alguns dados como CNPJ
                    $this->result = $this->soap->buscaCliente( $soapArgs );

                    // Pegando CNPJ e confirmando a existência dos dados    
                    $this->cnpj = $this->result->return->cnpj;    
                    if ( $this->cnpj != '' && count( $this->result->return->contratos->cartoesPostagem->servicos ) > 1 ):

                        // Pegando todos os códigos de serviço
                        foreach( $this->result->return->contratos->cartoesPostagem->servicos as $servico )
                            $this->servicos[ $servico->codigo * 1 ] = $servico->id * 1;

                        $this->servicoConectado = true;

                    else:
                        throw new Exception( 'Não foi possível localizar o cliente' );
                    endif;

                else:
                    throw new Exception( 'Serviço não conectado' );
                endif;

            } catch( Exception $e ) {

                $this->erro = 'Erro ao pegar serviços disponíveis: ' . $e->getMessage();
                $this->servicoConectado = false;

            }
        endif;

    }

    /**
    * Gera Etiquetas - retorna um array com as etiquetas geradas
    * @access public
    * @param integer $service   Servicço dos correios conforme tabela ( Ex.: PAC = 41106 )
    * @param integer $qtde      Quantidade de etiquetas
    */
    public function getLabels( $service, $qtde )
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada ):

            try {

                // Verifica se o serviço informado está disponível
                if ( ! count( $this->servicos ) > 1 || ! $this->servicos[ $service ] > 0 )
                    throw new Exception( "Não foi possível identificar o serviço $service" );

                // Solicita as etiquetas
                $soapArgs = array(
                    'tipoDestinatario' => 'C',
                    'identificador'    => $this->cnpj,
                    'idServico'        => $this->servicos[ $service ],
                    'qtdEtiquetas'     => $qtde,
                    'usuario'          => $this->dadosCliente->sig_user,
                    'senha'            => $this->dadosCliente->sig_pass
                );

                // Retorna a primeira e a última da sequencia de etiquetas reservadas, sem o dígito verificador
                $this->result = $this->soap->solicitaEtiquetas( $soapArgs );

                list( $etiquetaIni, $etiquetaFim ) = explode( ',', $this->result->return );


            } catch( Exception $e ) {

                $this->erro = 'Erro ao solicitar etiquetas: ' . $e->getMessage();
                return array();

            }

            try {

                // Se pegou as etiquetas
                if( $etiquetaIni != '' && $etiquetaFim != '' ):

                    // Monta sequencia de etiquetas
                    $umaEtiqueta = ( $etiquetaIni == $etiquetaFim );

                    // Montando sequência
                    if( $umaEtiqueta ):
                       $etiquetas = $etiquetaIni;

                    else:
                        // Padrão de etiquetas: 
                        // Qq/ coisa que não número com Zeros iniciais caso haja + Números + Qq/ coisa que não número
                        $regex = '/^([^0-9]+0*)([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)$/i';
                        // Caracteres inicias
                        $padraoIni = preg_replace( $regex, '$1', $etiquetaIni );
                        // Caracteres finais
                        $padraoFim = preg_replace( $regex, '$3', $etiquetaIni );
                        // Apenas números da etiqueta de início
                        $numInicial = preg_replace( $regex, '$2', $etiquetaIni );
                        // Apenas números da etiqueta de fim
                        $numFinal = preg_replace( $regex, '$2', $etiquetaFim );

                        $etiquetas = array();
                        for( $x = $numInicial; $x <= $numFinal; $x++ )
                            // Cada etiqueta é formado pelos caracteres inicias, número atual da sequencia, caracteres finais
                            $etiquetas[] = $padraoIni . $x . $padraoFim;
                    endif;

                    // Envia sequencia de etiquetas para solicitar dígitos verificadores
                    $soapArgs = array(
                        'etiquetas' => $etiquetas,       
                        'usuario'   => $this->dadosCliente->sig_user,
                        'senha'     => $this->dadosCliente->sig_pass
                    );

                    // Retorna o dígito verificador para cada etiqueta informada
                    $this->result = $this->soap->geraDigitoVerificadorEtiquetas( $soapArgs );

                    // Pegou o dígito verificador?
                    if( 
                        // Se tem mais de uma etiqueta
                        ( is_array( $this->result->return ) && count( $this->result->return ) > 0 ) || 
                        // Se tem apenas uma etiqueta
                        ( $this->result->return > 0 && $umaEtiqueta ) 
                    ):
                        // Gera o número final das etiquetas
                        if ( ! $umaEtiqueta ):
                            // Gera dígito para cada etiqueta
                            $etiquetasFinais = array();
                            foreach( $this->result->return as $index => $digito )
                                $etiquetasFinais[] = str_replace( ' ', $digito, $etiquetas[ $index ] );
                        else:
                            // Gera dígito para unica etiqueta
                            $etiquetasFinais[] = str_replace( ' ', $this->result->return, $etiquetas );
                        endif;

                        // Retorna as etiquetas
                        return $etiquetasFinais;

                    else:
                        throw new Exception( 'Não foi possível gerar o dígito verificador');
                        return array();
                    endif;    


                else:
                    throw new Exception( 'Não foi possível gerar as etiquetas' );
                endif;

            } catch( Exception $e ) {

                $this->erro = 'Erro ao solicitar dígito verificador: ' . $e->getMessage();
                return array();

            }
        else:
            return array();
        endif;
    }

    /**
    * Pega o usuário
    * @access public
    */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada )      
            return $this->dadosCliente->sig_user;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    /**
    * Pega a senha
    * @access public
    */
    public function getPass()
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada )      
            return $this->dadosCliente->sig_pass;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    /**
    * Pega o número do cartão de postagem
    * @access public
    */
    public function getCard()
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada )      
            return $this->dadosCliente->sig_cartao;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    /**
    * Pega o número do contrato
    * @access public
    */
    public function getContract()
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada )      
            return $this->dadosCliente->sig_contrato;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    /**
    * Pega os serviços disponíveis
    * @access public
    */
    public function getServices()
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada )      
            return $this->servicos;
        else
            return array();
    }

    /**
    * Modifica os dados
    * @access public
    * @param string $contract
    * @param string $card
    * @param string $user
    * @param string $pass
    */
    public function setClient( $contract, $card, $user, $pass )
    {
        if ( $this->lojaAutorizada ):

            // Tenta atualizar os dados
            $this->pdo->zeraVars();
            $this->pdo->setVars(array(
                'type' => 'UPDATE',
                'campos' => array(
                    'sig_user' => $user,
                    'sig_pass' => $pass,
                    'sig_cartao' => $card,
                    'sig_contrato' => $contract
                )
            ));
            // Se bão atualizou, retorna falso
            if( ! $this->pdo->execute() ):
                $this->erro = $this->pdo->erro;
                $this->sql = $this->pdo->sql;
                return false;
            endif;
            $this->sql = $this->pdo->sql;

            // Atualização feita com sucesso, pega novamente os dados
            $this->getData( false );
            return true;

        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente precisaram de realizar esta integração em um dos produtos aqui da empresa, eu até comecei à desenvolver uma biblioteca (que será disponibilizada no GitHub), mas ainda não tive tempo de terminar. Eu olhei esta biblioteca na época e até pensei em utiliza-la, mas esbarrei neste mesmo problema, me parece que ela segue a versão antiga da API do SIGEP dos correios, o que eu lhe sugiro é, posso pegar o código que comecei à desenvolver e coloca-lo em meu GitHub e tu me ajuda à desenvolver, ou pega os manuais abaixo e desenvolve você mesmo ou tente implementar dentro desta biblioteca já pronta.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PFM9KL_IJpeWJaUnAwNC1xV0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Estou desenvolvendo a partir do manual. A princípio parece que consegui. Porém, ainda vou aguardar para ver se alguém tem uma solução pra biblioteca acima.

Answer (score 0):

É possível que você esteja passando alguma informação errada para o PHP Sigep.
Por favor, poste o código que você está utilizando para gerar as etiquetas para eu poder te ajudar.

De qualquer forma, é importante ressaltar duas coisas:

- **Você não pode gerar etiquetas usando o servidor de homologação dos Correios**. Então você vai precisar de um usuário e senha real (que
  você consegue com o Correios). Veja esse exemplo:
  http://phpsigep.stavarengo.com/site/php/php-sigep/exemplos/solicitarEtiquetas.php
- Desde maio de 2014 o PHP Sigep está preparado para trabalhar com a
  última versão do Web Service do Correios, por tanto, garanta que você está usando a
  última versão do projeto.

Existem outros exemplos alem do que foi citado acima. Você encontra todos eles aqui: https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep/tree/master/exemplos

Comment: Não, não. O problema não é esse. O problema é que o projeto não faz o caminho completo. Nos exemplos na url citada, simplesmente se solicita as etiquetas. Antes, porém, é necessário obter o status do cartão, depois pegar os serviços disponíveis para o contrato, e só então os correios permite a reserva de etiquetas. Essas informações são do próprio correio. Uma solução simples pra quem quer apenas gerar etiquetas, está na classe que postei acima. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Szag-Ot, nós não fazemos este caminho e não tivemos o problema que você está tento. Pode me mostrar onde está documentado que isso deve ser feito? Com a documentação em mãos podemos atualizar o PHP Sigep.

Comment: No manual (fluxograma na página 9). Em conversa por email eles informaram isso. A princípio disse, cheio de razão, que não, e ainda indiquei o site modelo de vcs (http://stavarengo.github.io/php-sigep/) que, por sinal, agora está com erro, dizendo que nesse site era feito o caminho direto e funcionava. Eles informaram que é não é possível fazer a chamada direta sem passar por esses processos e informaram a página do manual onde mostra o caminho completo para se solicitar as etiquetas (pág. 9). Por isso fiz meu próprio código com a chamada de métodos na ordem que eles informam e voilá!

Comment: (Veja o funcionamento do meu código de teste em http://tmwecommerce.com.br/config/sigep/teste-gera-etiquetas.php?service=41068)

Comment: Legal, @Szag-Ot. Eu vou olhar o manual e fazer os ajustes necessários.   
Obrigado pelo Feedback.

Comment: Dei um fork no projeto e subi a última versão do manual... (https://github.com/szagot/php-sigep/tree/master/manual). Apropósito, parabéns pela iniciativa no projeto. Ele é bem completo.